# Substituting Nulls

Tags: sql, ms-access, null

We have the following table (populated from a data extract from a separate table) with 3 fields:

[image]

The table's contents ( /original data source contents) are strictly controlled so that, while Null values can be present in either Ax or Ay, they will never be present in both.

Records 1,2 and 3 are identical with respect to the following agreed rule:
"Where a Null value is present then the field entry's value shall be taken from the neighbouring non-null Ax/Ay"
With this, Records 1,2 and 3 are interpreted as having Ax and Ay values of 1.

Currently, when performing data analysis, all sql constructs must account for the possible presence of Nulls with the net result that the sql complexity/number of conditions to be checked for is increased which also results in an increased risk of introducing a human error. These risks are amplified in the real table which contains many more similar field pairs where similar rules can be applied. 
Since all analysis is looking only at the table of extract data and not the original/source data...

--> would it be *acceptable practice* in this case to pre-prepare/modify the extract table via an UPDATE to pad all such encountered Null values with the respective neighbouring field? 
...with the aim of achieving simpler to write/read, perhaps more efficient/faster executing sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to update the table, this is a path I recommend you not to walk at.
The table is meant for storing the data, not processing it.
What you are looking for is a `View` for displaying the table as it was meant to be seen, including the agreed rules you have for your data.

For example, for the following code (SQL-Server):

```
 CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ax] [int] NULL,
    [Ay] [int] NULL
  )



CREATE VIEW MyView
  AS
  SELECT ID,
        CASE 
         WHEN Ax IS NULL THEN Ay
         Else Ax END 
         as Ax,
        CASE 
        WHEN Ay IS NULL THEN Ax
         Else Ay 
         END as Ay
FROM  MyTable       

INSERT INTO MyTable 
VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO MyTable 
VALUES(1,NULL)
INSERT INTO MyTable 
VALUES(NULL,1)
INSERT INTO MyTable 
VALUES(1,2)

SELECT * FROM MyTable
SELECT * FROM MyView
```

I get:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, and I apologise for not mentioning that we're using MS Access - I don't think Views are supported. However, could this (Update usage in my original post) ever be classed as 'data cleaning' in that we are pre preparing the table for analysis, and this table is a copy from the original data source?

Comment: I think MS Access [does support views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836312.aspx)

Comment: As for your question, I think it makes more sense to do the 'sanitizing' upon insertion of the data. Avoid holding data in a form that is not useful for you (which sounds like this is your case...)

Comment: That makes good sense. I'll see if there's any way the extract sql could be modified to perform some sanitizing, or, the process around accompanying schema .csv extract import stage. Views is something I've not used before and yes, I now see it is supported in Access so I'll check that out also.